# How to resolve "A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-id/..." on boot?

Tags: boot, opensuse, fstab, btrfs

After I cloned my smaller Linux disk onto a larger disk and put it into my computer and booted, I started getting the message

> A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-id/INTEL-...160{something_else_here}

and this message holds for 90 seconds before the system can continue to boot.

I included the number 160 in the device path above because this clearly indicates the old disk, which was of the size 160GB. So it appears the system is somehow looking for the old disk while booting from the new disk.

How can I get rid of that message during the boot time?

I don't see anything pointing to the old disk in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /                       btrfs  defaults                      0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /var                    btrfs  subvol=/@/var                 0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /usr/local              btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local           0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /tmp                    btrfs  subvol=/@/tmp                 0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /srv                    btrfs  subvol=/@/srv                 0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /root                   btrfs  subvol=/@/root                0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /opt                    btrfs  subvol=/@/opt                 0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /home                   btrfs  subvol=/@/home                0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /boot/grub2/i386-pc     btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/i386-pc  0  0
UUID=A2E6-577D                             /boot/efi               vfat   defaults                      0  0
UUID=2345e607-926a-48ce-b80a-5f5487fca8a8  /.snapshots             btrfs  subvol=/@/.snapshots          0  0
/dev/sda4                                  swap                    swap   defaults                      0  0
```

Where should I look?
The system is OpenSUSE, UEFI boot.

Comment: If you run `grep -r "/dev/disk/by-id/INTEL" /etc` as root, what do you get?

Comment: @telcoM I get entries pointing to `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb3`. It looks like I have corresponding files in `/dev/disk/by-id/`, and so I'm wondering if they are attempted to be mounted automatically, and if removing the files would solve the issue?

Comment: That will be difficult to answer without knowing what those entries actually are. I think SuSE has/had a system that uses/used udev rules to persist the `/dev/sd*` device names, i.e. if a device was `/dev/sdb` once, it tried its best to ensure that the same disk would stay `/dev/sdb` forever for this OS installation, unless specifically changed. If those entries were in a file named something like  `/etc/udev/rules.d/*persistent*.rules`, then you probably should remove them, since all your mounts seem to be by UUID.

Comment: @telcoM I used the command you suggested and determined there was a relevant entry in `/etc/default/grub`, so I commented out an entire section containing that entry in that file and then ran `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, rebooted, and the problem gone. Thanks for your help!